# Load blob image data into QPixmap

Tags: python, image, pyqt, blob, qpixmap

I am writing a program using PyQt4 for front-end GUI and this program accesses a back-end database (which can be either MySQL or SQLite). I need to store some image data in the database and below is the Python code I use to import image files (in JPEG format) to a blob data field in the database:

```
def dump_image(imgfile):
    i = open(imgfile, 'rb')
    i.seek(0)
    w = i.read()
    i.close()
    return cPickle.dumps(w,1)

blob = dump_image(imgfile)
hex_str = blob.encode('hex') 
# x"%s"%hex_str will be the string inserted into the SQL command
```

This part works fine. My question is about how to create a QPixmap object from the image data stored in the database in PyQt4. My current approach involves the following steps:

(1) Hex str in database -- cPickle&StringIO --> PIL Image Object

```
def load_image(s):
    o = cPickle.loads(s)
    c = StringIO.StringIO()
    c.write(o)
    c.seek(0)
    im = Image.open(c)
    return im
```

(2) PIL Image Object -->Temporary image file

(3) Temporary image file --> QPixmap

This approach also works fine. But it would be better if I don't have to write/read temporary image files which may slow down the program response to user interactions. I guess I could use [QPixmap::loadFromData()](http://docs.huihoo.com/pyqt/pyqt4/html/qpixmap.html#loadFromData) to directly load from the blob data stored in the database and hope someone here could show me an example on how to use this function.

TIA,

Bing

Comment: Why do you even use the PIL step? Qt is perfectly happy with loading JPEG data: http://docs.huihoo.com/pyqt/pyqt4/html/qpixmap.html#reading-and-writing-image-files

Comment: I am sure Qt is able to load JPEG data. What I am looking for is a code snippet that converts the string encoded in the blob field to the
QPixmap object. Thanks!

Comment: I figured out I can just use QPixmap::loadFromData(cPickle.loads(s)) where s is the string data fetched from the blob field.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the QImage.fromData static method to load an image from a string and then convert it to a pixmap:

```
 image_data = get_image_data_from_blob()
 qimg = QtGui.QImage.fromData(image_data)
 pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qimg)
```

Answer (score 4):

The approach suggested by Ants Aasma works and actually it is also OK to just use the following code:

```
image_data = cPickle.loads(str(s)) # s is fetched from DB 
qp = QPixmap() 
qp.loadFromData(image_data)
```

Thanks a lot for all the help and information.

Answer (score 0):

After a good hour and a half of googleing to solve a similar problem, I ended up loading JPEGs in a compiled .exe with QT. I am using python3.1, and therefore could not use some of the previously mentioned solutions :

- tips working for py2exe (because I am using cxfreeze instead of py2exe, as py2exe works only for python2),
- tips that require PIL (also only for python2, afaik).

While the solutions posted here didn't work, something very similar did :
I simply copied the `[PythonDir]\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\imageformats` to my exe's folder and removed the `qt.conf` file that I created in that folder following other solutions. That's all (I think :p).

After that, it worked whether I loaded the jpg using `QPixmap`'s constructor or loading a `QImage` first. It also worked with no special option needed for both the `setup.py` and the `cxfreeze.bat` methods of compiling to exe using cxfreeze.

(this solution was posted by jbz on http://www.thetoryparty.com/wp/2009/08/27/pyqt-and-py2app-seriously-i-dont-know-what-to-do-with-you-when-youre-like-this/)

This question is a bit old, but as the problem seems to be still there, I hope this answer will help python3.1 users out there.