# Displaying Image (in bytes) in PyQt

Tags: python, image, pyqt, byte, google-maps-static-api

I need to know how to display an image in bytes in GUI.
I am taking an image from google static map API with .content I get the image in bytes like this:

```
import requests

a = requests.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Berkeley,CA&zoom=14&size=400x400')
print(a.content)
```

I want to display it in the interface i am creating.
I know that i can save the bytes in an image and then create a `QPixmap` loading the image and adding it to a scene or maybe a `Qlabel`, but can I display the image in the interface without saving it?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: To clarify, the thing you want to avoid is saving it to a file or you want to avoid having to use a qlabel or graphics scene to display it?

Comment: sorry i wasnt clear enough i want to avoid saving it only

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1300908/1994235

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will want to use [`QPixmap.loadFromData()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#loadFromData-3).

```
qp = QPixmap()
qp.loadFromData(my_bytes)
```