# Displaying a received image in pyqt

Tags: python, image, sockets, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to display image that I receive from a test local server inside pyqt window. I tried this link but I couldn't get it work. Could you help with that? Thanks in advance.

[Displaying Image (in bytes) in PyQt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096325/displaying-image-in-bytes-in-pyqt)

Client Code

```
import socket
from PIL import Image
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = QWidget()
label = QLabel(widget)

HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PORT = 5000

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((HOST, PORT))

while True:
    image_binaries = s.recv(100000000)
    if not image_binaries:
        break
    #img = Image.open(BytesIO(image_binaries))


pixmap = QPixmap()
pixmap.loadFromData(image_binaries)
label.setPixmap(pixmap)
widget.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())

widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Server Code

```
import socket

HOST = "0.0.0.0"
PORT = 5000

s = socket.socket()
s.bind((HOST, PORT))

data = open(r'Screenshot_1.jpg', 'rb').read()
print("Waiting  for connection...")

s.listen(5)
while True:
    client, client_address = s.accept()
    print(client_address, "is connected")
    client.send(data)
```

Comment: @eyllanesc I added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different problems in this code.

First is that the reading loop is wrong. TCP is a stream protocol. That means that the data may come in a variable number of packets that you must concatenate. So it should be:

```
image_binaries = b""
while True:
    chunk = s.recv(100000000)
    if not chunk:
        break
    image_binaries += chunk
s.close()
```

Then you have a possible race condition server side. `client.send(data)` will return as soon as all the data has been queued for transmission. If another connection immediately occurs, `client` will be reused which could cause the previous connection do be closed before everything has been sent. You should use a [graceful shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27777498/3545273) here:

```
while True:
    client, client_address = s.accept()
    print(client_address, "is connected")
    client.send(data)
    client.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)   # notify that nothing more is to be sent
    _ = client.recv(16)               # wait for the client to close when everything has been received
    client.close()                    # Ok, we can explicitely close
```